# How to point domain to dynamic ip?

Tags: networking, dns

I've domain name on xx.xx.eu.org (free domain).

And I want to point this domain to my home server which have dynamic IP,
I can enter only an IP to point to, can't put address (like no-ip domain) in the domain settings.

Is there any way to do it?

I don't want to use dynamic DNS services because I want to use my xx.xx.eu.org domain if it's possible first.

Many thanks.

Comment: What kind of control do you even have? A webinterface? An API perhaps? Can you set the DNS TTL? Can you set a CNAME entry?

Comment: You need to be able to set CNAME or nameservers for your  domain.

Comment: It's very simple web interface and I can only add or change  A records. no CNAME or other advanced settings.

Answer (score 3):

`noip.com` has a paid feature called [Plus Managed DNS](https://www.noip.com/remote-access) that lets you use your own domain (*xx.xx.eu.org*, in your case) with their dynamic services.

Comment: Do you know any free service like this?
I tried namecheap.com, cloudns.net and freedns.afraid.org but I failed to set it up (and I don't know if they have what I need)